# Solving the problem through KKT condition

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

This is my optimization problem where $n$ is the only decision variable of the problem:

\begin{align}
\min_{n} \quad &c n  
\\ \text{subject to:}\quad &\sum_{i \in I}
    D_{i}x_i \lambda_i < n 
\\ &\frac{nD_{i}x_i}{n - \sum_{i' \in I}D_{i'}x_{i'} \lambda_{i'}} \leq \overline{LR}_i \quad  \forall  i \in I 
\\ & n \leq N 
\\ & n \in \mathbb N 
\end{align}

Can I use KKT condition to solve this problem? If so, since I have multiple constraints (one for each i $\in I$), How I can solve it and obtain optimal $n$ ?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: What is given, and what are the variables?  Are $D_i,x_i,\lambda,I$ constants that are given?  If so, why isn't this trivial?

Comment: @D.W. As I mentioned in the question, $n$ is the only variable in the problem which means the rest are parameters. Since $I$ is a set, so I have several constraint for each i in that set. I edited and simplified the equations by dropping x and lambda.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation.  Please provide the context in which you encountered this problem and some motivation about why this will be relevant and useful to others in the future.  Our mission is to build an archive of knowledge that will help others, in the form of questions and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is trivial.  You don't need KKT.  Your first inequality has the form

$$\alpha < n$$

for some known constant $\alpha$, since $\sum_{i \in I} D_i x_i \lambda^i$ is a constant.  Your second inequality has the form

$${\beta_i n \over n - \alpha} \le \gamma_i,$$

for some known constants $\beta_i,\gamma_i$, since $D_i x_i$ is a constant.  This inequality is equivalent to

$$\beta_i n \le \gamma_i n - \alpha \gamma_i,$$

which is in turn equivalent to

$$n \ge {-\alpha \gamma_i \over \gamma_i - \beta_i}$$

if $\beta_i < \gamma_i$; or equivalent to

$$n \le {-\alpha \gamma_i \over \beta_i - \gamma_i}$$

if $\beta_i > \gamma_i$.

Therefore, your "subject to" constraints are all of the form $n \le d_i$ or $n \ge e_i$ for some constants $d_i,e_i$.  It follows that they are equivalent to

$$\max_i e_i \le n \le \min_i d_i.$$

You can compute the constants $d_i,e_i$, find their min/max, and thereby find the allowable range for $n$.  Now, assuming $c>0$, the minimum possible value of $cn$ over this range will happen when $n$ is at its minimal allowable value, i.e., $n = \max_i e_i$.  It follows that it is trivial to solve your constraint system.